# Can I optimise this Matlab for loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, if-statement, optimization

I have the following code:

```
np = 25;
j = 1:3;
count = 2;

for i = 2:total_NN
   A(i) = B(j) * C(count, :)'; 
   count = count + 1;

   % When this condition is met we will add to j and reset count:
   if rem(i-np, np-1) == 0 
       j = j + 2; 
       count = 2; 
   end
end
```

I am trying to optimise it by removing the inner if statement and retaining its functionality. I tried doing this but it did not work nor eliminated the if statement:

```
for i = 2:total_NN
   A(i) = B(j) * C(count, :)'; 
   count = count + 1;

   z = rem(i-np, np-1) != 0;
   j = j + 2*z;

   if rem(i-np, np-1) == 0  
       count = 2; 
   end
end
```

What can I do? The if statement is slowing down my code immensely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the `if` condition before the loop for every index

```
np = 25;
j = 1:3;
count = 2;
iArr = 2:total_NN;
r = (rem(iArr-np,np-1) == 0);

for ii = iArr 
   i = iArr(ii);

   A(i) = B(j) * C(count, :)'; 
   count = count + 1;

   % When this condition is met we will add to j and reset count:
   if r(ii)
       j = j + 2; 
       count = 2; 
   end
end
```

Without a complete example to test or sense of memory constraints it's hard to validate any further optimisations, but you could likely define

```
jArr = (1:3) + 2*cumsum(r(:)); % all j values from the loop, select j=jArr(ii,:) for each loop
```

And something similar for `count` before the loop. At which point you may even be able to vectorise the entire matrix operation but that's beyond the scope of this question.